# Alignment in Legend in R

Tags: r, graph

I plot a graph in R as shown below. It is all right except the legend. I would like to aline the symbols xi and beta so that it will be esaier for people to compare different parameters. At the moment, I use the following command to add legend.

```
install.packages("fExtremes"); library(fExtremes)
install.packages("tikzDevice"); library(tikzDevice)

pgpd.11 <- function(x) pgpd(x, xi=1, beta=1)
pgpd.01 <- function(x) pgpd(x, xi=0, beta=1)
pgpd.n051 <- function(x) pgpd(x, xi=-0.5, beta=1)
pgpd.n11 <- function(x) pgpd(x, xi=-1, beta=1)
pgpd.n21 <- function(x) pgpd(x, xi=-1.2, beta=1)

tikz("GPDCDF.tex", width=4, height=3)
par(mar=c(2, 2, 0.1, 0.1))
plot(seq(0, 5, by=0.01), pgpd.11(seq(0, 5, by=0.01)), type="l", ylim=c(0, 1), xlab="", ylab="C.D.F")
lines(seq(0, 5, by=0.01), pgpd.01(seq(0, 5, by=0.01)), lty=2)
lines(seq(0, 5, by=0.01), pgpd.n051(seq(0, 5, by=0.01)), lty=3)
lines(seq(0, 5, by=0.01), pgpd.n11(seq(0, 5, by=0.01)), lty=4)
lines(seq(0, 5, by=0.01), pgpd.n21(seq(0, 5, by=0.01)), lty=5)
legend("bottomright", c("$\\xi=1, \\beta=1$", "$\\xi=0$, \\beta=1", "$\\xi=-0.5, \\beta=1$", "$\\xi=-1, \\beta=1$", "$\\xi=-1.2, \\beta=1$"), lty=1:5)
dev.off()
```

Is there a way to make all beta aligned, please? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the third, and hopefully final, edit.

```
 plot(1:10)

legend(6,5, c(expression(paste(xi, " = 1,")), expression(paste(xi, " = 0,")), expression(paste(xi, " = -0.5,")), expression(paste(xi, " = -1,")), expression(paste(xi, " = -2,"))), lty=1:5, bty='n')

legend(7.6,5, c(expression(paste(beta, "=1")), expression(paste(beta, "=1")),expression(paste(beta, "=1")),expression(paste(beta, "=1")),expression(paste(beta, "=1"))), bty='n')

dev.copy(png, 'betaAlign.png');dev.off()
```

[image]

I think I've figured out a different way (shown above). Two different legends. What do you think?

Comment: The \ character should work. I just used the space bar here and was able to do it. Maybe I'm just not understanding the question. I also have no idea how you were able to produce the symbols using the `tex` style, so I'm a little jealous there. 

`plot(1:10)`

`legend("bottomright", c(expression(paste(xi, " = 1,     ", beta, " = 1")), expression(paste(xi, " = 0,     ", beta, " = 1")), expression(paste(xi, " = -0.5, ", beta, " = 1")), expression(paste(xi, " = -1,    ", beta, " = 1")),expression(paste(xi, " = -2,    ", beta, " = 1"))) , lty=1:5)`

Comment: I do not know how you get it. I still cannot align betas. See my update. By the way, to get LaTeX symbol, you need to use package tikzDevice.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's still not the best response. I apologize. I think it's almost there though. Thanks for the info about the tikzDevice package.